# min-height in vh vs % for body?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to understand a code, why is there a need to specify for body

```
body{
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   min-height: 100vh;
}
```

to have min-height: 100vh after setting the html to

```
html {
   height: 100%;
}

body,
html {
   margin: 0;
   min-height: 100%;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   padding: 0
}
```

to height: 100% then body,html to min-height: 100%? Also why not just use min-height: 100% for body?

Comment: share code or relevant snippet please

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Before defining any property to html or body, we should know one thing i.e.

`Viewport > html > body`

**Mind the difference between viewport and html, body in theimage below.**

[image: Here is an image to make it more clear]

`height: 100vh` = 100% of the viewport height

`height: 100%`= 100% of the parent's element height

The viewport units are relative units, which means that they do not have an objective measurement. Instead, their size is determined by the size of the viewport.

Viewport Height : vh --- 1/100th of the height of the viewport.

Whereas the size of an element defined in percentage is determined by its parent element, we can only have an element fill the entire height of the screen if the parent element also fills the entire height of the screen.

That is why you need to add `height: 100%` on html and body, as they don't have a size by default and viewport is parent for html.

Comment: html has no parent why declare min-height: 100%;?

Comment: Adding height: 100% to <html> isn't a good idea. If you do that, the html ist just as height as the browser window und the longer content flows out of html. This can produce strange behaviors and is hard to debug. What you can do is min-height: 100vh; on the <body> element to fit the screen viewport size and let it grow if the content is longer. The html will also have the same size as the body. :)