# expand body height css

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to expand my body tag to full browser height to fully display background color. I understand there are some solutions that suggest using html tag height of 100% and body tag with height of 100% or min-height of 100%.

I have found a solution (below) that has achieved the same result by specifying a min-height of the full view port and this works on different browsers. Could I use this as an alternative solution? If any, what are the disadvantages of this solution? Please provide some supporting evidence.

```
body {
background-color:#ea7400;
height: 100%;
min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Some further information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41793228/min-height-in-vh-vs-for-body

Comment: @Josethehose Thank you, that was helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [min-height in vh vs % for body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41793228/min-height-in-vh-vs-for-body)

Comment: @Persijn That post was a helpful resource, but I tried to use other resources to provide an optimal solution in my answer. What input do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Josethehose provided a comment directing me to useful information on my question. See [min-height in vh vs % for body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41793228/min-height-in-vh-vs-for-body)

While my solution did work, I don't believe it is the optimal solution because it uses unnecessary code.

**Explanation:**
The html, and body tags don't have default heights and can be sized relative to their parent elements. **The hierarchy is Viewport > HTML > Body**. The actual size of the browser screen is Viewport, so specifying the `height: 100%` for the html tag will ensure it is the full height of its parent element or the Viewport. The `height: 100%` can be coupled with the body tag to achieve full height of the parent element or the html tag which is inherited from the Viewport.

The optimal solution would be:

```
 html,
 body {
 height: 100%;
 }
```